# Regarding Issue with Multi-Lang in Storm While Running Python (WordCountTopology )

Tags: python, apache-storm

I am trying to run the WordCountTopology in storm local mode before running my own application and I am unable to run it. I am continuously getting the following error. I have verified that the `splitsentence.py` file is kept at the `multilang/resources` directory which is in the `examples/storm-starter` directory.

```
5729 [Thread-22-split-executor[7 7]] ERROR o.a.s.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
Serializer Exception:
python: can't open file 'splitsentence.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

        at org.apache.storm.utils.ShellProcess.launch(ShellProcess.java:91) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt.prepare(ShellBolt.java:131) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4973$fn__4986.invoke(executor.clj:791) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__557.invoke(util.clj:482) [storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_51]
5734 [Thread-30-spout-executor[9 9]] INFO  o.a.s.d.executor - Opening spout spout:(9)
5734 [Thread-28-split-executor[6 6]] ERROR o.a.s.util - Async loop died!
```

I have followed the instructions during installation and built my package successfully with maven. My storm version is 1.0.3 and my python version is 2.7.13. I ran the ExclamationTopology and some of my own code which does not need multi-language support and it works like a charm.

I am not able to understand why the multi-lang support in storm is not working. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My problem has got resolved. I just wanted to reply to let others know about the issue. I was using the storm version 1.0.3 which has the problem and the fix is mentioned below.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-2450

I upgraded my version to one of the fix versions, i.e. 1.0.4 and it is working fine.